# Odd DateTime.Now() behaviour

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I'm having a weird issue where DateTime.Now is returning the incorrect time when I'm calling it for the purposes of timestamping a logfile. The code in question is as follows:

```
string logDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
string logTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM:ss");
string wLine = "[" + logDate + " " + logTime + "] " + line;
Console.WriteLine(wLine);
```

Where the 'line' variable is a string passed to that particular method.
The date is fine, and the time inside the logTime variable is 20 minutes slower than it should be. The clock on the machine running this application is right, and if I delete the text file that it's writing to, it's recreated as soon as the app is run again, and the created / modified stamps on the file itself are correct.

Given that the filesystem reports the time on the file correctly, I'm stumped as to why DateTime.Now is 20 minutes slower - and I'm sure it's not a DST issue as we only ever move 1 hour at a time.

Has anyone else seen this issue or could at least point me in the right direction?

TIA

Comment: don't you mean `H:mm:ss` I'm pretty sure `MM` is month, More info on string formats for DateTime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Also - Don't use `DateTime.Now`.  You will have ambiguity during the DST "fall-back" transition.  Use `DateTimeOffset.Now`, or `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.  See http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try change this :

```
string logTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM:ss");
```

with

```
string logTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

MM = month not minute

Comment: +1, for minutes it should be lower case `mm`, upper case `MM` is for month

Comment: Thanks, what a silly mistake - however in this case I did want to leave the 24hour format, so have stuck to HH rather than hh.

Answer (score 0):

'MM' means month
'mm' means minutes

You can make your code easier:
Just write

```
string wLine = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("G") + "] " + line;
```

instead of

```
string wLine = "[" + logDate + " " + logTime + "] " + line;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) you can find additional information about `Standart String.Formats Of DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Console.WriteLine("[{0:G}] {1}", DateTime.Now, line);
```